# How to add external libraries to my application in android

Tags: android, android-build

I have an application that I have to look at as a training exercise. It has used few external libraries such as SlidingMenu, ImageViewZoom and ActionbarSherlock.

I have downloaded and extracted those libraries but I have no idea how to add them to my existing project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Right Way:**

What you need to do is to copy the external library (`JAR` file) to the `/libs` folder of your project.

That way those libraries will compile with your project and could be use on real device when you deploy your application.

Some times you will need to add a project to your `workspace` ( For example the Google Map library)
and then add the library reference using the `properites -> Android` window at the bottom.

You can get an idea of how it's done by reading the first 3 step of this Google Map API V2 guide I wrote. there I reference the android library project:

[Google Map API V2 Guide](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

**The Wrong Way:**

any other way, like for example adding the files using the `properties - > Java build path` screen may result in a missing library when you run the project on a real device.

Comment: That is true only for libraries that are JARs, not Android library projects. At least one of the above (ActionBarSherlock) is an Android library project.

Comment: Yeah you right I will add the android library option (like google maps) as well.

Comment: @EmilAdz I don't see any JAR files in any of the libraries that i downloaded. So, does that mean they are Android Library Projects?

Answer (score 4):

For those that are distributed as a simple JAR, do what Emil Adz indicates, and copy that JAR into your project's `libs/` directory.

For those, like ActionBarSherlock, that are distribute as Android library projects, you will need to do a bit more work. In the case of Eclipse, you will need to import the library project into your workspace, then go into Project > Properties > Android for your application project and click the [Add] button to add the library  project to the application project. For a command-line build, use **`android update lib-project`** to link the application and library project together.

You can read more about referencing an Android library project [from Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) or [the command line](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) in the documentation.

Comment: Okie.. Thanks for the answer. I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import those libraries as *Android Project from existing source* and mark them as "Is Library" by going into their properties.

Once you marked it as "Is Library" add it to your
 project by going into Properties->Android->Library->Add (it will show the list of library you imported).

Answer (score 0):

if they are jars the make a `libs` folder then paste  the jar in it and then go to your project `buildpath`->`configure build path`->`Add Jars`-> `ok` and if it is a library project then go to your project `Property`->`Android`->`Add`(Your Lib Project)->`Ok`->`Apply`